# Finding all the roots (rational, irrational, and complex) of a polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$x^6-64$$

I have already tried using synthetic division but get stuck after the 3rd round of division. Then I tried looking at it as a difference of squares. That didn't clear anything up either. Can I get a nudge in the right direction? Please.

Comment: Can you think of what one of its roots might be?

Comment: $2^2=??; 2^3=??,2^4=??\cdots$

Comment: Yes, from the first two rounds of synthetic division I know that -2 and 2 are two of its roots

Comment: consider dividing $x^6-64$ by $(x+2)(x-2)$..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x^{6} - 64 = x^6 - (2)^{6}= (x^{3})^{2} - (2^3)^{2} $$

$$= (x^3 -2^3)(x^3 +2^3)= (x -2)(x^2+2x +4)(x+2)(x^{2} - 2x+2)$$

From here will be easy to find the roots!!!

Comment: Almost too easy... thank you. I didn't look at it correctly.
I used the wrong exponents when trying to look at it as a difference of squares.

Comment: you're welcome!! :)

Answer (score 2):

So basically $$x^6-64=0 \implies x^6=64$$ Since $x \in \mathbb{C}$ we write $64$ using cosines and sines, i.e. $64=64(\cos 2k \pi + i \sin 2k \pi)$ so $$x=(64(\cos 2k \pi + i \sin 2k \pi))^{1/6} \implies x=2\left(\cos \frac{2k\pi}{6} + i \sin \frac{2k\pi}{6}\right)$$ Now if you plug in $k=0,1,2,3,4,5$ you'll get distinct solutions. Note that $k=6$ would give you a repeating solution.

Comment: Wow!! Excellent answer!!!

Comment: This is a more *routine* way of going about solving such questions, but it's more tedious perhaps!

Comment: yes, but mathematically beautiful!!